# valgrind in QNX: Can't access shared library Error

Tags: valgrind, arm64, qnx-neutrino

I've downloaded valgrind from https://community.qnx.com/sf/frs/do/listReleases/projects.valgrind/frs.valgrind for QNX.
OS details:

```
#uname -a
QNX localhost 7.1.0S 2021/02/12-21:06:45EST SA8540P_v2.1_ft0_ADP_Ride_v1.0.2_UFS_NORMAL aarch64le

# ls -l
total 282423
drwxr-xr-x   3 default   1000           4096 Apr 30  2015 armle-v7
drwxr-xr-x   3 default   1000           4096 Apr 30  2015 usr
drwxr-xr-x   3 default   1000           4096 Apr 30  2015 x86

# ls -l /var/valgrind/armle-v7/usr
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   2 default   1000           4096 Apr 30  2015 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 default   1000           4096 Apr 30  2015 lib

# ls -l

total 917
-rwxr-xr-x   1 default   1000          41112 Apr 30  2015 callgrind_annotate
-rwxr-xr-x   1 default   1000          12016 Apr 30  2015 callgrind_control
-rwxr-xr-x   1 default   1000          32170 Apr 30  2015 cg_annotate
-rwxr-xr-x   1 default   1000          10418 Apr 30  2015 cg_diff
-rwxr-xr-x   1 default   1000          71060 Apr 30  2015 cg_merge
-rwxr-xr-x   1 default   1000          24398 Apr 30  2015 ms_print
-rwxr-xr-x   1 default   1000          53202 Apr 30  2015 **valgrind**
-rwxr-xr-x   1 default   1000          96364 Apr 30  2015 valgrind-di-server
-rwxr-xr-x   1 default   1000          35454 Apr 30  2015 valgrind-listener
-rwxr-xr-x   1 default   1000          90877 Apr 30  2015 vgdb
```

I am entirely new to QNX.

1. Should I use armle-v7 or x86?
2. Can I directly run valgrind under bin:

```
   valgrind <my-program> <input arg>
  If i try this I get the below error:
**sh: ./valgrind: Can't access shared library**

Even version command gives the same error:
# /var/valgrind/armle-v7/usr/bin/valgrind --version
sh: /var/valgrind/armle-v7/usr/bin/valgrind: Can't access shared library
```

3. Should I copy the valgrind to /usr/bin or some other folder? I've already exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the libraries needed by my executable and also valgrind lib path[/var/valgrind/armle-v7/usr/lib]
4. Basically I need to analyze memory leak and crash in my program[Note: Don't have QNX Momentics IDE]. From QNX software centre, can we download valgrind?

Comment: The valgrind you downloaded was compiled for the wrong architecture. You need arm64/aarch64, not armv7 or x86.

Comment: I could not find any pre-built valgrind for arm64/aarch64 QNX platform. If we build sa8540p-qx-1-0_hlos_dev_qnx-*** from https://chipcode.qti.qualcomm.com/ with any setting, will we get valgrind packages? any idea?